# How can R-Studio access R packages from local repo

Tags: rstudio

We have installed R-Studio in Linux server which does not have access to Internet. But for R-Studio needs to download & update R-Packages as and when required.

All our desktops runs windows OS. Is there a way out to have for R-Studio from Linux server to access a local repo from where R-Packages can be downloaded ?

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely. All you need to do is set up your own CRAN-like repository. You can do this conveniently with e.g. the [miniCRAN package](http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2014/10/introducing-minicran.html).

Once you have a repository set up, you can use the `Rprofile.site` file to permanently direct users to your local repository ([here are instructions](http://www.r-bloggers.com/permanently-setting-the-cran-repository/)).